# NameError: name 'Janela' is not defined

Tags: python, classes, tkinter

Estou seguindo esse [PDF](https://www.dcc.ufrj.br/~fabiom/mab225/tutorialtkinter.pdf), estou na página 10, o código dá erro e eu não sei o porquê.

```
from tkinter import *
class Janela:
    def __init__(self,toplevel):
        self.fr1 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr1.pack()

        self.botao1 = Button(self.fr1,text='Oi!')
        self.botao1['background']='green'
        self.botao1['font']=('Verdana','12','italic','bold')
        self.botao1['height']=3
        self.botao1.pack()

        self.botao2 = Button(self.fr1,bg='red', font=('Times','16'))
        self.botao2['text']='Tchau!'
        self.botao2['fg']='yellow'
        self.botao2['width']=12
        self.botao2.pack()

    raiz=Tk()
    Janela(raiz)
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É um problema de indentação. Python tem o que chamamos *white space* significativo, então quando indenta está criando um bloco. No documento *linkado* as 3 últimas linhas estão no primeiro nível, no seu código elas estão no nível da classe, ou seja, está chamando um código dentro da classe, mas ela ainda está sendo definida. O correto:

```
from tkinter import *
class Janela:
    def __init__(self,toplevel):
        self.fr1 = Frame(toplevel)
        self.fr1.pack()

        self.botao1 = Button(self.fr1,text='Oi!')
        self.botao1['background']='green'
        self.botao1['font']=('Verdana','12','italic','bold')
        self.botao1['height']=3
        self.botao1.pack()

        self.botao2 = Button(self.fr1,bg='red', font=('Times','16'))
        self.botao2['text']='Tchau!'
        self.botao2['fg']='yellow'
        self.botao2['width']=12
        self.botao2.pack()

raiz=Tk()
Janela(raiz)
raiz.mainloop()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/IndentClass.py).